# WAV file recorded with wrong header

Tags: sample-rate, wav

I have some WAV files that whose actual sound contents are at 44100Hz, but the headers incorrectly state that the sample rate is 48000Hz (I think this is due to the DAW setting its own sample rate OK but failing to set the interface's sample rate properly).

What can be done to change the headers of the WAV files to make programs interpret their contents as 44100Hz? Specifically, which tools are available for either Linux or Windows that can achieve this?

Thanks!

(In case I am not making sense, I really don't think I need to resample the WAV files at a different rate.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most direct, if somewhat "hands-dirty", way of doing this is to manipulate the header with a hex editor. There are two entries in the RIFF header that need to be modified: the sample rate itself, which is `80 BB 00 00` in 32-bit little-endian,

[image: 48k sample rate in RIFF head]

and the adjacent *byte rate*, 192k or `00 EE 02 00` for a 48k 16-bit stereo file. (96k for mono-16bit, 288k for 24bit-stereo, etc.)

[image: 192k byte rate in RIFF head]

These need to be changed to 44.1k / `44 AC 00 00`

[image: 44.1k sample rate in RIFF head]

and 176.4k / `10 B1 02 00`

[image: 176.4k byte rate in RIFF head]

respectively.

In summary: change `80 BB 00 00 00 EE 02 00` to `44 AC 00 00 10 B1 02 00`!

Comment: No guarantees that this will work with less standard wav files, e.g. including a BEXT-chunk etc....

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME

Comment: This is epic. I will have to try it. I hope my wav files are standard since they were created by Reaper

Comment: Actually, the presence of a BEXT chunk (or JUNK, etc) won't matter. You just have to find the "fmt " chunk, which you can easily do either by searching, or by following the 'chain of chunks'.

Comment: Works perfectly on my wav files. I had different byte rates but it was easy to calculate the required numbers

Answer (score 7):

Very easy. Just use SoX:

```
sox -r 44.1k infile.wav outfile.wav
```

The `-r 44.1k` overrides the header information in `infile.wav` and will not perform any effects on the samples themselves.

More info: sox.sf.net

Comment: Note this is great for small files, but not so much for large files because it will re-write all the sound data as well.

Comment: @cmc , this information is _very_ helpful to know. Now, I understand some performance issues I've been having. You should post a separate answer discussing the limitation of `sox` and discussing options without re-write. I thought of using `ffmpeg`, but I think that `ffmpeg` uses `sox` under the hood. I think [the hex-editor answer](https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/33011/25747) is great and helped me learn more about fundamental issues, but I'd like something that's more batch-friendly. If this needs to be a separate question, I'll research it and, (if I don't find it), I'll ask it.

Answer (score 5):

After some more searching, I have found that `ffmpeg` is able to do this by converting the WAV to raw PCM format, and then converting back to WAV with the correct sample rate in the header.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le output.pcm
```

to convert input.wav to raw PCM data. Then

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 1 -i output.pcm file_FIXED.wav
```

to convert back to a WAV with sample rate 44.1K.

Answer (score 3):

One way i do this, using Adobe Audition, is to "Open as" raw PCM data (one has to type an * in the name bar of the opening window to show all files), and then define the sample rate and mono/stereo information in the pop up box that comes up.

This has proved useful for opening files that were stopped while recording in programs like Ableton Live.